# Where should this question about programming contest composition go?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422434/what-algorithms-are-general-requisites-for-programming-competitions-specifical/28422912#28422912

is unfortunately off-topic for SO because it's not a programming question.  However, it's a good "soft" question that has a fairly solid answer.  (In particular, it's not "primarily opinion-based"; the high-school contests have a well-defined syllabus and the non-high-school contests are pretty much no-holds-barred.)

Does this question belong on another Stack Exchange site?  Can it be moved there?

Comment: You are asking for a *list*, which makes it too broad for the Q&A format.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am, or the asker of the linked question is?  My point is that there is a canonical list here.

Comment: Yet anyone with an opinion will jump in and add to the list. What you'll get is low-quality dross, over and over and over again.

Comment: I missed that this is about someone else asking the question. But yes, they cannot ask the question on a Q&A site. Even if the question *could* be kept to just one canonical authoritative answer, you'd still have a broken window here, an off-topic question kept on the site for other broad list question authors to point at going *but that question is not closed*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK, I'll trust your judgment on this and drop it.  You could very well be right about that.  (The list I'm talking about is official and published by the IOI.)  Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @tmyklebu The question is asking what would be the "best" topics for him to cover on the contest he's creating.  A list of topics covered by some other contest is not answering that at all.  They may not be the "best" topics to be covered for his competition.

Comment: @tmyklebu: but the question you link to also asks *but also in general*. It is not about one competition here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: To be clear, I think of this question more like a less-frivolous version of "what are all the integers at least 1 and at most 17?," which would be a "list question" of sorts but has exactly one well-defined answer.  The "but also in general" part is problematic but could be edited out.

Comment: @tmyklebu: the question is not worded that way though. Not that there is a SE site where asking about competitions is on-topic, even if we could just narrow this down sufficiently to allow for just those integers (topics) by citing the source.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK, I think you've covered all the bases here and erased the doubt in my mind.  If you post an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Stack Exchange site where the *topic* would be covered.

In addition, the question is too broad. It is asking for a list. Even if that list can be dug up from an official source and communicated, the question is no less a *list me all the possible items* question for it.

Such questions *in general* don't fit the Q&A format; they attract an endless parade of low-quality answers from people that don't see why *their* opinion on what should be added to the list isn't being appreciated. And even if you could somehow keep those types of answers out, you'd still have a broken window here, a post authors of *other* list questions would point to and say *but that question isn't closed!*

Answer (score 1):

A question like that isn't going to be acceptable anywhere on the SE network.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: The comments here are delving into heated bickering. If you have an answer, please post it as such. if you have a question for clarification; please post it as a comment. If you want to get into a protracted debate about the definition of 'broad', then maybe that should be its own meta question?